# Get the column name while getting error information

Tags: sql-server

I have used stored procedure and it throws the exception when the data is passed with an error. I have return the error statement by use built-in functions like `ERROR_NUMBER()`, `ERROR_MESSAGE()`, `ERROR_PROCEDURE()`.

But I also need to display the which column in a table getting the problem.

For example, a table `Employee` has two fields like `EmpName` and `EmpDate`.

Here `EmpDate` is `DateTime` datetype. If I am going to insert the `varchar` value means it throws the exception like:

> Conversion failed when date/time to varchar

by using `ERROR_MESSAGE()`. I also need to get the column name which is caused by error: `EmpDate`

Is there any built-in function like other ERROR related function?

Comment: Related connect item: https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/339410/please-fix-the-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-message-to-give-the-column-name

Answer (score 0):

Similar thing has been discussed below:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/83a79294-9e1c-4d27-bfca-b6c75d33d778/get-column-name-key-value-when-error-occurs